# How to properly pass form data in php?

Tags: php, html, post, get, wamp

I'm using php to build a small form that requires passing 2 variables for processing.

I got the example off w3schools and although the info gets passed in the URL, the php form doesn't process it in any way (let alone extract it).

I'm just wondering if there might be anything wrong with my WAMP server.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    welcome
    Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>.<br />
     You are <?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?> years old!
    </body>
    </html>
```

HTML form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://        www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;                 charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="get">
     Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
     Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
     <input type="submit" />
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you make sure that `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` in your `php.ini`? Add any errors you are receiving in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not processing? Don't you get an html with at least those "welcome" words? Then the issue is with the path to the processing php file. Check whether it is exist in the same directory as the form html file.

Comment: What exactly is happening when the form redirects to welcome.php? can you please post the exact output of welcome.php in that case?

Comment: It redirects me to the right page and there php prints what it's supposed to, only the variables are completely empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed as already noted by various posts, this code should work.
In my experience the php tags are output directly if they're not parsed.
Do you see anything on the page at all? You could also check the sourcecode of the page and check if you can spot anything wrong there.

Also when copying from examples on the internet, sometimes you get weird characters that interrupt the parser. Usually this results in an error (which is not the case here), there's no harm in checking though.

Try outputing something simple and see if that works:

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Can't think of anything else at the moment...

Comment: Okay well I tested your code on an XAMP setup and it worked fine.
Maybe the [track_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) isn't set? Try doing it with POST and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Make sure that you are viewing the page via the server and not directly, if your URL looks anything like `file://path/to/file.php` then that is wrong. You have to start the server and then access it with `http://localhost/file.php`. [Tutorial (start with step 16)](http://www.eacomm.com/support/manuals/wamp_install/)

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine code-wise. Did you save the php file in the same directory as 'welcome.php'?

Comment: yes. even if a write php script in html is not working. simple <? php print("WELCOME") ?> is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems correct. Does PHP work? Does

```
echo phpinfo();
```

work? If yes, what does

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

give you? Do the GET parameters appear there?

Comment: So PHP does not work? If so, you should indeed investigate your server setup!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` after that run your page for example page  `http://localhost/yourpage.php` again, now just see whether error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = 1 is set or not if not then you have to configure your php.ini,

Comment: file://localhost/C:/wamp/www/new.php                                  i have added and the result is                                       <? php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: @Eugen :) why are u put the space between <? and php ?? use this <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Check URL if you can view values in url and still can't able to fetch it then try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and my suggestion is to try to submit form in same page because when i was fresher i write both codes in same page but action page is different so i was confused why its not working

Answer (score -1):

This script should work as far as I can see. What is your WAMP-setup?

Try to upload the script on a free server that uses php and run it there.

Comment: why you need a session_start for processing a form submission?

Comment: what setting? I use wamp 2.2.